# Grep concatenation in C

Tags: c, grep, fork

I am trying to do a multiple grep using c language.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int pid1, pid2;
    int stdout = 1;
    int pipefd[2];

    char* name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char* year = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    bzero(name, sizeof(name));
    bzero(year, sizeof(year));

    pid1 = fork();

    if(pid1 == 0){
        strcpy(name, "Jack");
        strcpy(year, "2018");
        close(1);

        if(pipe(pipefd) == -1){
            perror("pipe");
            exit(-1);
        }

        pid2 = fork();
        dup(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", year, "file.txt", (char*)NULL);

        if(pid2 == 0){
            read(pipefd[0], &stdout, sizeof(stdout));
            int a = dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            execlp("grep", "grep", name, a, (char*)NULL);
        }
    } else if (pid1 < 0){
        printf("pid error\n");
    }
}
```

So basically it gives me error in the first exec, saying that the file descriptor is invalid. I didn't find a solution to pass the result of the first exec to the second fork.

Comment: You try run some code *after* one `exec` call, but if `exec` is successful, the calling process is replaced by the one created by `exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program behaves like this (I only look at `fork` and `exec` calls):

- creation: process A
- `fork`: you have 2 processes: A(parent) and B(child)
- you do nothing more in A
- in B, you make a `fork`: you have 2 processes B and C its child
- in both B and C you `exec` a grep command.
- *your* code is no longer executed in B and C : they have been replaced by `grep` processes.

But, you were not far to a solution.

What you have to do is:

- create a pipe in the parent process
- create the first child

  - setup its i/o
  - exec the child program
- create the second child

  - setup its i/o
  - exec the child program
- wait for child to end.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int pid1, pid2;
    int stdout = 1;
    int pipefd[2];

    /* patterns to search */
    char name[] = "Jack";
    char year[] = "2018";

    /* pipe creation */
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* create first child */
    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", year, "file.txt", (char *) NULL);
    }

    /* second child */
    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", name, "-", (char *) NULL);
    }

    /* close pipe to prevent child hang up */
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    while (1) {
        pid_t cid = wait(NULL);
        if (-1 == cid)
            break;
        printf("process %d terminated\n", cid);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, I also find errors in my code that I understand. But it still doesn't work, it seems that the main difference is the order of execution you did, can you explain how the second fork works, if you placed it after the first exec? In my code, I placed it before the first exec to make sure is executed.

Comment: You should execute the close on the second end of the pipe. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The rule also applies with either `dup()` or [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) with `F_DUPFD`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok, thanks, I was not sure of that. Should I close fds 0 and 1 too?

Comment: If you mean 0 as standard input and 1 as standard output, then no; the use of `dup2()` means you don't need that.  The code in the question closed `1` before creating the pipe; the read end of the pipe will have been on file descriptor `1` as a result, which leads to all sorts of confusion.  Your code avoided that sort of travesty.